# Can I use "from __future__ import unicode_literals" in a master import file?

Tags: python

I'm creating some demonstration Python scripts that must work under 2.6, 2.7, and 3.3.

As part of that, each module is prefixed with

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
```

Can this directive be cut from each of the modules and pasted into a common import file instead?

E.g.

```
# master.py
from __future__ import unicode_literals

# file1.py
import master

# file2.py
import master
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. Quoting the documentation:

> A future statement is a directive to the compiler that a particular module should be compiled using syntax or semantics that will be available in a specified future release of Python.

(http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#future)

The `__feature__` imports affect only the current module.

Answer (score 2):

No. Compiler flags (which is how `__future__` is implemented) only affect compilation of the current module.